Tomtom API search by street
The documentation is very light and there is not support offered.
So what I'm trying to achieve (or figure out if it's achievable), is to search by street name in a given country using Tomtom's search api.
You can set the country, which is great, but that's it.
If I want to search for all oxford streets in the UK and set the query value to 'oxford str', it returns everything what has oxford in it, which is not what I want.
I would probably should use the autocomplete endpoint, but that's even confusing and restricted. If I set the same parameters, it returns nothing.
Is it doable what I want, or this API is simply just built to search for shops and restaurants?

Ant reason you're restricting yourself to the Tomtom API? Google Places API is much better featured, and will most likely do what you need out of the box: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search

Pricing is the main reason, the cheapest option I found so far. By brand I imagined it a better built API. I will possibly end up using something else, maybe google places.

With TomTom you can use idxSet=Str param to search for streets only

ouuh God, that's what I was after ... and with the typeahead parameter set it does exactly what I need. I had another look at the documentation, it's there but it's not obvious what that parameter does. Maybe I should have looked more into it.
Thanks a lot.
It seems, that you added your suggestion as a comment and not an answer, I cannot mark it as the solution.

With TomTom you can use idxSet=Str param to search for streets only
